# Upload big file stop at 1GB gaufrette phpseclinb

Tags: php, symfony, phpseclib, gaufrette

I'm trying simple copy files between server sftp using gaufrette and phpseclib.
Local adapter server no problem sends more than 1GB. If i am trying send remote always stops at 1GB logs look like

```
    00000fe0  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00  ................
00000ff0  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00  ................
00001000  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00                          ........

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:1c:00:00:00:18:65:00:00:00  ............e...
00000010  01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:07:53:75:63:63:65:73:73  .........Success
00000020  00:00:00:00                                      ....

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:1c:00:00:00:18:65:00:00:00  ............e...
00000010  01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:07:53:75:63:63:65:73:73  .........Success
00000020  00:00:00:00                                      ....

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:1c:00:00:00:18:65:00:00:00  ............e...
00000010  01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:07:53:75:63:63:65:73:73  .........Success
00000020  00:00:00:00                                      ....

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:1c:00:00:00:18:65:00:00:00  ............e...
00000010  01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:07:53:75:63:63:65:73:73  .........Success
00000020  00:00:00:00                                      ....

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:1c:00:00:00:18:65:00:00:00  ............e...
00000010  01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:07:53:75:63:63:65:73:73  .........Success
00000020  00:00:00:00                                      ....

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:1c:00:00:00:18:65:00:00:00  ............e...
00000010  01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:07:53:75:63:63:65:73:73  .........Success
00000020  00:00:00:00                                      ....

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:1c:00:00:00:18:65:00:00:00  ............e...
00000010  01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:07:53:75:63:63:65:73:73  .........Success
00000020  00:00:00:00                                      ....

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA (since last: 0.0009, network: 0.0008s)
00000000  00:00:01:00:00:00:00:1c:00:00:00:18:65:00:00:00  ............e...
00000010  01:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:07:53:75:63:63:65:73:73  .........Success
00000020  00:00:00:00                                      ....

<- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  d3:0d:5e:69:3d:0d:7f:e8:13:a6:fd:85:f6:05:3c:02  ..^i=...........
00000010  00:00:00:d4:63:75:72:76:65:32:35:35:31:39:2d:73  ....curve25519-s
00000020  68:61:32:35:36:40:6c:69:62:73:73:68:2e:6f:72:67  ha256@libssh.org
00000030  2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e:69:73:74:70  ,ecdh-sha2-nistp
00000040  32:35:36:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e:69  256,ecdh-sha2-ni
00000050  73:74:70:33:38:34:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32  stp384,ecdh-sha2
00000060  2d:6e:69:73:74:70:35:32:31:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65  -nistp521,diffie
00000070  2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:2d:65  -hellman-group-e
00000080  78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:32:35:36:2c:64  xchange-sha256,d
00000090  69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72  iffie-hellman-gr
000000a0  6f:75:70:2d:65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61  oup-exchange-sha
000000b0  31:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e  1,diffie-hellman
000000c0  2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:34:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64:69  -group14-sha1,di
000000d0  66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f  ffie-hellman-gro
000000e0  75:70:31:2d:73:68:61:31:00:00:00:27:73:73:68:2d  up1-sha1...'ssh-
000000f0  72:73:61:2c:65:63:64:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e  rsa,ecdsa-sha2-n
00000100  69:73:74:70:32:35:36:2c:73:73:68:2d:65:64:32:35  istp256,ssh-ed25
00000110  35:31:39:00:00:00:e9:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74  519....aes128-ct
00000120  72:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73  r,aes192-ctr,aes
00000130  32:35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:72:63:66:6f:75:72:32  256-ctr,arcfour2
00000140  35:36:2c:61:72:63:66:6f:75:72:31:32:38:2c:61:65  56,arcfour128,ae
00000150  73:31:32:38:2d:67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68  s128-gcm@openssh
00000160  2e:63:6f:6d:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:67:63:6d:40  .com,aes256-gcm@
00000170  6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:63:68:61:63  openssh.com,chac
00000180  68:61:32:30:2d:70:6f:6c:79:31:33:30:35:40:6f:70  ha20-poly1305@op
00000190  65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38  enssh.com,aes128
000001a0  2d:63:62:63:2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63:62:63:2c:62:6c  -cbc,3des-cbc,bl
000001b0  6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:2c:63:61:73:74:31  owfish-cbc,cast1
000001c0  32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:62  28-cbc,aes192-cb
000001d0  63:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:72:63  c,aes256-cbc,arc
000001e0  66:6f:75:72:2c:72:69:6a:6e:64:61:65:6c:2d:63:62  four,rijndael-cb
000001f0  63:40:6c:79:73:61:74:6f:72:2e:6c:69:75:2e:73:65  c@lysator.liu.se
00000200  00:00:00:e9:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61  ....aes128-ctr,a
00000210  65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36  es192-ctr,aes256
00000220  2d:63:74:72:2c:61:72:63:66:6f:75:72:32:35:36:2c  -ctr,arcfour256,
00000230  61:72:63:66:6f:75:72:31:32:38:2c:61:65:73:31:32  arcfour128,aes12
00000240  38:2d:67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f  8-gcm@openssh.co
00000250  6d:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65  m,aes256-gcm@ope
00000260  6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:63:68:61:63:68:61:32  nssh.com,chacha2
00000270  30:2d:70:6f:6c:79:31:33:30:35:40:6f:70:65:6e:73  0-poly1305@opens
00000280  73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:62  sh.com,aes128-cb
00000290  63:2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63:62:63:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66  c,3des-cbc,blowf
000002a0  69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:2c:63:61:73:74:31:32:38:2d  ish-cbc,cast128-
000002b0  63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:2c:61  cbc,aes192-cbc,a
000002c0  65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:72:63:66:6f:75  es256-cbc,arcfou
000002d0  72:2c:72:69:6a:6e:64:61:65:6c:2d:63:62:63:40:6c  r,rijndael-cbc@l
000002e0  79:73:61:74:6f:72:2e:6c:69:75:2e:73:65:00:00:01  ysator.liu.se...
000002f0  92:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70  .hmac-md5-etm@op
00000300  65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73  enssh.com,hmac-s
00000310  68:61:31:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e  ha1-etm@openssh.
00000320  63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:36:34:2d:65:74:6d:40  com,umac-64-etm@
00000330  6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63  openssh.com,umac
00000340  2d:31:32:38:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68  -128-etm@openssh
00000350  2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32  .com,hmac-sha2-2
00000360  35:36:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63  56-etm@openssh.c
00000370  6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32  om,hmac-sha2-512
00000380  2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d  -etm@openssh.com
00000390  2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:72:69:70:65:6d:64:31:36:30:2d  ,hmac-ripemd160-
000003a0  65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c  etm@openssh.com,
000003b0  68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d:39:36:2d:65:74:6d  hmac-sha1-96-etm
000003c0  40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61  @openssh.com,hma
000003d0  63:2d:6d:64:35:2d:39:36:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65  c-md5-96-etm@ope
000003e0  6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64  nssh.com,hmac-md
000003f0  35:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:75:6d:61:63  5,hmac-sha1,umac
00000400  2d:36:34:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c  -64@openssh.com,
00000410  75:6d:61:63:2d:31:32:38:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68  umac-128@openssh
00000420  2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32  .com,hmac-sha2-2
00000430  35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32  56,hmac-sha2-512
00000440  2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:72:69:70:65:6d:64:31:36:30:2c  ,hmac-ripemd160,
00000450  68:6d:61:63:2d:72:69:70:65:6d:64:31:36:30:40:6f  hmac-ripemd160@o
00000460  70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d  penssh.com,hmac-
00000470  73:68:61:31:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35  sha1-96,hmac-md5
00000480  2d:39:36:00:00:01:92:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:2d  -96....hmac-md5-
00000490  65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c  etm@openssh.com,
000004a0  68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70  hmac-sha1-etm@op
000004b0  65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:36  enssh.com,umac-6
000004c0  34:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f  4-etm@openssh.co
000004d0  6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:31:32:38:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f  m,umac-128-etm@o
000004e0  70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d  penssh.com,hmac-
000004f0  73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65  sha2-256-etm@ope
00000500  6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68  nssh.com,hmac-sh
00000510  61:32:2d:35:31:32:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73  a2-512-etm@opens
00000520  73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:72:69:70:65  sh.com,hmac-ripe
00000530  6d:64:31:36:30:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73  md160-etm@openss
00000540  68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d  h.com,hmac-sha1-
00000550  39:36:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63  96-etm@openssh.c
00000560  6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:2d:39:36:2d:65  om,hmac-md5-96-e
00000570  74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68  tm@openssh.com,h
00000580  6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61  mac-md5,hmac-sha
00000590  31:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:36:34:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73  1,umac-64@openss
000005a0  68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:31:32:38:40:6f  h.com,umac-128@o
000005b0  70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d  penssh.com,hmac-
000005c0  73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68  sha2-256,hmac-sh
000005d0  61:32:2d:35:31:32:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:72:69:70:65  a2-512,hmac-ripe
000005e0  6d:64:31:36:30:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:72:69:70:65:6d  md160,hmac-ripem
000005f0  64:31:36:30:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d  d160@openssh.com
00000600  2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d  ,hmac-sha1-96,hm
00000610  61:63:2d:6d:64:35:2d:39:36:00:00:00:15:6e:6f:6e  ac-md5-96....non
00000620  65:2c:7a:6c:69:62:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63  e,zlib@openssh.c
00000630  6f:6d:00:00:00:15:6e:6f:6e:65:2c:7a:6c:69:62:40  om....none,zlib@
00000640  6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00:00:00  openssh.com.....
00000650  00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00                          ........

-> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.0001, network: 0s)
00000000  e0:dc:b7:cf:3a:4a:e8:be:96:1e:ec:59:03:39:8e:8e  ....:J.....Y.9..
00000010  00:00:00:7e:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d  ...~diffie-hellm
00000020  61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64  an-group1-sha1,d
00000030  69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72  iffie-hellman-gr
00000040  6f:75:70:31:34:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64:69:66:66:69  oup14-sha1,diffi
00000050  65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:2d  e-hellman-group-
00000060  65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64:69  exchange-sha1,di
00000070  66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f  ffie-hellman-gro
00000080  75:70:2d:65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:32  up-exchange-sha2
00000090  35:36:00:00:00:0f:73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:2c:73:73  56....ssh-rsa,ss
000000a0  68:2d:64:73:73:00:00:00:e9:61:72:63:66:6f:75:72  h-dss....arcfour
000000b0  32:35:36:2c:61:72:63:66:6f:75:72:31:32:38:2c:61  256,arcfour128,a
000000c0  65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32  es128-ctr,aes192
000000d0  2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c  -ctr,aes256-ctr,
000000e0  74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:74  twofish128-ctr,t
000000f0  77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77  wofish192-ctr,tw
00000100  6f:66:69:73:68:32:35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73  ofish256-ctr,aes
00000110  31:32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63  128-cbc,aes192-c
00000120  62:63:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77  bc,aes256-cbc,tw
00000130  6f:66:69:73:68:31:32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f  ofish128-cbc,two
00000140  66:69:73:68:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66  fish192-cbc,twof
00000150  69:73:68:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69  ish256-cbc,twofi
00000160  73:68:2d:63:62:63:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d  sh-cbc,blowfish-
00000170  63:74:72:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62:63  ctr,blowfish-cbc
00000180  2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63:74:72:2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63  ,3des-ctr,3des-c
00000190  62:63:00:00:00:e9:61:72:63:66:6f:75:72:32:35:36  bc....arcfour256
000001a0  2c:61:72:63:66:6f:75:72:31:32:38:2c:61:65:73:31  ,arcfour128,aes1
000001b0  32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:74  28-ctr,aes192-ct
000001c0  72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f  r,aes256-ctr,two
000001d0  66:69:73:68:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66  fish128-ctr,twof
000001e0  69:73:68:31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69  ish192-ctr,twofi
000001f0  73:68:32:35:36:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38  sh256-ctr,aes128
00000200  2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:2c  -cbc,aes192-cbc,
00000210  61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69  aes256-cbc,twofi
00000220  73:68:31:32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73  sh128-cbc,twofis
00000230  68:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68  h192-cbc,twofish
00000240  32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:2d  256-cbc,twofish-
00000250  63:62:63:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:74:72  cbc,blowfish-ctr
00000260  2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:2c:33:64  ,blowfish-cbc,3d
00000270  65:73:2d:63:74:72:2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63:62:63:00  es-ctr,3des-cbc.
00000280  00:00:39:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36  ..9hmac-sha2-256
00000290  2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d  ,hmac-sha1-96,hm
000002a0  61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35  ac-sha1,hmac-md5
000002b0  2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:00:00:00:39  -96,hmac-md5...9
000002c0  68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:68:6d  hmac-sha2-256,hm
000002d0  61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d  ac-sha1-96,hmac-
000002e0  73:68:61:31:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:2d:39:36  sha1,hmac-md5-96
000002f0  2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:00:00:00:04:6e:6f:6e  ,hmac-md5....non
00000300  65:00:00:00:04:6e:6f:6e:65:00:00:00:00:00:00:00  e....none.......
00000310  00:00:00:00:00:00                                ......
```

i've tested connection like filezilla sftp and no problem sends ober 1GB, any idea? Gaufrette looks like have not many options maybe phpseclib?

Second though it can be SFTP server problem but if is, i think is should be problem in sending  file by filezilla.

Comment: maybe alter your php_ini file to allow max upload=1024

Comment: php.ini seems does not matter, i have only 50MB in it and works in local SFTP serwer fine

Comment: I would setup a shutdown handler, http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php  This will catch any errors that cause PHP to stop, then you may be able to see it could be many things, Max Memory, time limit etc..

Comment: exception like this:  Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: User Notice: Expected SSH_MSG_KEXINIT in /home/marek/Workspace/sftp/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php:1467

Comment: register-shutdown gives:   [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
  Warning: preg_match(): Subject is too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem on server site. We have tested on other account and there was no problem. Restart service sshd and update fix problem.
In all logs that i set there was no errors :/.
Admin said that probally it was some corrupt in package and sftp stopped services at 1GB. More strange is that, if we send by filezilla there was no problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

This should be fixed in the latest git version of phpseclib, with this commit:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/commit/b50dde76f5683367e64e9f5e2936412d3168dad3

**Long Answer**

It's failing at the key re-exchange. Quoting [RFC 4253 § 9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-9):

> It is RECOMMENDED that the keys be changed after each gigabyte of
> transmitted data or after each hour of connection time, whichever
> comes sooner.  However, since the re-exchange is a public key
> operation, it requires a fair amount of processing power and should
> not be performed too often.

I was able to reproduce the issue (and verify the fix) with the following Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        printf "\n\nRekeyLimit 1K" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        service ssh restart
    SHELL
end
```

The issue appears to have been introduced with this pull request (which was merged in between the 2.0.6 and 2.0.7 releases):

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/pull/1162

Ideally a unit test would exist for this but phpseclib would probably need to use Docker for their unit tests, which they're not currently.